# Can't get Request Body with ContentCachingRequestWrapper

Tags: java, spring-boot, post, request, response

I am trying to log my request and response body with ContentCachingRequestWrapper and ContentCachingResponseWrapper. I used them as below:

```
@Component
public class RequestResponseLoggingFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RequestResponseLoggingFilter.class);

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        ContentCachingRequestWrapper wrappedRequest = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);
        ContentCachingResponseWrapper wrappedResponse = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);
    
            logRequest(wrappedRequest);

            filterChain.doFilter(wrappedRequest, wrappedResponse);
                   
            logResponse(wrappedResponse);
            
            wrappedResponse.copyBodyToResponse();
        }
    }

    private void logRequest(ContentCachingRequestWrapper wrappedRequest) {
        logger.info("Request: {} {}", wrappedRequest.getMethod(), wrappedRequest.getRequestURI());

       
        byte[] requestBody = request.getContentAsByteArray();
        if (requestBody.length > 0) {
            String requestBodyString = new String(requestBody, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            logger.info("Request Body: {}", requestBodyString);
        }
    }

    private void logResponse(ContentCachingResponseWrapper wrappedResponse) {
        logger.info("Response: {}", wrappedResponse.getStatus());
     
        byte[] responseBody = response.getContentAsByteArray();
        if (responseBody.length > 0) {
            String responseBodyString = new String(responseBody, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            logger.info("Response Body: {}", responseBodyString);
        }
    }
}
```

I can get response body right, but my request body returns empty, why?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you share the calling code? How are you calling `doFilterInternal()`. Also, what sort of request is the `HttpServletRequest`, the properties, i.e. GET/POST and other properties.

Comment: Are you able to get the request body if you call the `wrappedRequest.getMethod()` in the `logRequest` method?